# Chromium and Chromedriver do not work correctly, permission denied

Tags: permissions, apache2, google-chrome, chromium, headless

I'm trying to automate some features with `php-chrome` library.

I need to use `chromium.chromedriver` installed on my server.

So I installed these apps.

```
root@afs2:~#: google-chrome --version
Google Chrome 116.0.5845.140
```

and

```
root@afs2:~# chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 116.0.5845.96 (1a391816688002153ef791ffe60d9e899a71a037-refs/branch-heads/5845@{#1382})
```

But when I try to use chromedriver, I have this errors:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: Chrome process stopped before startup completed. Additional info: cmd_run.go:1046: WARNING: cannot create user data directory: cannot update the 'current' symlink of "/var/www/snap/chromium/current": remove /var/www/snap/chromium/current: permission denied Sorry, home directories outside of /home needs configuration. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/11209 for details. in /var/www/afsv.com/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Browser/BrowserProcess.php:410 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/afsv.com/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Utils.php(60): HeadlessChromium\Browser\BrowserProcess->HeadlessChromium\Browser{closure}() #1 /var/www/afsv.com/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Browser/BrowserProcess.php(450): HeadlessChromium\Utils::tryWithTimeout() #2 /var/www/afsv.com/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Browser/BrowserProcess.php(139): HeadlessChromium\Browser\BrowserProcess->waitForStartup() #3 /var/www/afsv.com/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/BrowserFactory.php(81): HeadlessChromium\Browser\BrowserProcess->start() #4 /va in /var/www/afsv.com/vendor/chrome-php/chrome/src/Browser/BrowserProcess.php on line 410

Does anyone know how can I fix this?

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: what do you get if you write in the terminal `type google-chrome` ?

Comment: @hanshenrik [47555:47555:0831/105059.466408:ERROR:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(100)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.

Comment: no way, I don't believe `type google-chrome` would ever give that error. screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

given that you're using `chrome-php` , my best guess is that you have a problem with your `\HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory` .. first run in in the terminal

> type google-chrome

you should get something like

```
google-chrome is /snap/bin/google-chrome
```

then take the path from that and give it to your BrowserFactory:

```
$browserFactory = new \HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory('/snap/bin/google-chrome');
```

and given that your `google-chrome --version` worked, the BrowserFactory should also be able to work with this google-chrome binary :)